# Create database in other database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new to SQL Server, and I'm asking if can I create a database in other database like this:

```
mydatabase1[database] -> mydatabase2[database] -> mytable[table]
```

Comment: question in current form makes no sense.

Comment: What does your example mean? How would this impact querying or storage for exapmple?

Comment: A database in SQL Server can contain tables, views, procedures, function and many more database objects - but **not** another database - you **cannot** "nest" databases

Comment: What functionality are you trying to actually achieve here? This might be an xy question.

Comment: @MitchWheat . . . I think the question makes a lot of sense for someone who is new to databases.  The short answer is that databases are not directories and tables are not files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  SQL Server stores data in a hierarchy, consisting of:

- Tables are in schema.
- Schema are in databases.
- Databases are in servers.

The full access for a table uses a four-part naming convention:  `server.database.schema.table`.  However, most code does not use all four.

If you are thinking that databases are like folders and tables are like files, then that is the wrong analogy.